# Pagination in duplicate rescords

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, pagination

I need to apply pagination in a spring boot project.
I apply pagination in 2 queries. Each of them gives me data from different tables. Now, some of these records are identical in the two tables hence need to be removed.
At the end, the number of entries that I need to send will be reduced, thereby ruining the initial pagination applied. How do I go about this? What should be my approach?

Here I take 2 lists from 2 jpa calls(highRiskCust and amlPositiveCust) that will apply pagination, then remove the duplicacy and return the final result (tempReport).
`

```
            List<L1ComplianceResponseDTO> highRiskCust = customerKyc.findAllHighRiskL1Returned(startDateTime, endDateTime,agentIds);
            List<L1ComplianceResponseDTO> amlPositiveCust = customerKyc.findAllAmlPositiveL1Returned(startDateTime, endDateTime,agentIds);
            List<L1ComplianceResponseDTO> tempReport = new ArrayList<>(); 
            tempReport.addAll(amlPositiveCust);
            tempReport.addAll(highRiskCust);
            tempReport = tempReport.stream().filter(distinctByKey(p -> p.getKycTicketId())) 
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`

Answer (score 1):

In order to have pagination working, you need to do it with a unique request.
Fondammently this request should use `UNION`.
Since JPA does not support `UNION`, either you do a native query or you change you query logic using outer joins.